# Implicit looping through numpy array to replace values

Tags: python, loops, replace, implicit

I'm new to python and am trying to find a way to implicitly replace values in "array_to_replace" with one of two values in "values_to_use" based on the values in "array_of_positions":

First, the setup:

```
values_to_use = np.array([[0.5, 0.3, 0.4], [0.6, 0.7, 0.75]])
array_of_positions = np.array([0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1])
array_to_replace = np.array([[5, 5, 4], [6, 5, 4], [1, 2, 3], [9, 9, 9], [8, 8, 8], [7, 7, 7], [6, 5, 7], [5, 7, 9], [1, 3, 5], [3, 3, 3]])
```

Then, the brute force way to do what I want, which is to replace values in "array_to_replace" based on conditional values in "array_of_positions", is something like the following:

```
for pos in range(0, len(aray_to_replace)):
   if (array_of_positions[pos] == 0):
      array_to_replace[pos] = values_to_use[0]
   else:
      array_to_replace[pos] = values_to_use[1]
```

Would you have any recommendations on how to do this happen implicitly?

Comment: Please _explain_ what you try to accomplish. What is "this" in "to do this"?

Comment: Thanks.  I modified my question to hopefully make it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

The answer for this turned out to be pretty simple.  To get what I wanted, all I needed to do was the following:

print values_to_use[array_of_positions]

This gave me what I needed.